# If for every $n$ there is a $g_n$ continuous such that $|f(x)-g_n(x)|<\frac1n$ then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following property:

> For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a function $g_n\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous in $a$ such that $|f(x)-g_n(x)|<\frac1n \; \forall x \in (a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n)$.

Prove $f$ is continuous in $a$.

My stupid attempt:
I don't know how to connect this property with the definition of continuous function. 
$$\begin{align}|f(x)-f(a)| &= |f(x)-g_n(x)+g_n(x)-f(a)| \leq |f(x)-g_n(x)|+|f(a)-g_n(x)| \\
&< \frac1n + |f(a)-g_n(x)| \to 0\end{align}$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $n$ such that $\frac 1 n <\frac {\epsilon} 3$. Then $|f(x)-f(a)|\leq |f(x)-g_n(x)|+|g_n(x)-g_n(a)|+|g_n(a)-f(a)|$. The first and the last term are less than $\frac {\epsilon} 3$ (provided $x \in (a-\frac 1 n , a+\frac  1 n))$. The middle term is also less than $\frac {\epsilon} 3$ provided $|x-a| <\delta$ where $0<\delta < \frac 1  n$ is determined by the continuity of $g_n$. Hence $|f(x)-f(a)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a| <\delta$.

Comment: In short: "almost there with the triangle inequality, but the OP should have gone one step further to also use continuity of the $g_n$'s."

Answer (score 0):

You got:
$$
|f(x) - f(a)| < \frac{1}{n} + |f(a) - g_n(x)|
$$
You can go on in like:
$$
|f(a) - g_n(x)| = |f(a) - g_n(a) + g_n(a) - g_n(x)| < |f(a) - g_n(a)| + |g_n(a) - g_n(x)| < \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon
$$
Above result uses the continuity of $g_n$. The rest of solution is obvious!